# Show images in different android devices

Tags: android

How to show images in different android devices at same position of mobile screen ? i want to build a game screen in android in which i need to shows my pieces (tokens) are display at same position even we used different devices like tablets, smartphone and etc,

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed positions like top-left, top-right, bottom-left ,bottom-right, center kind of images you can directly use Relative layout and display the images.

There is another way if those images remain static then u can simply use image and image hotspot with drawable-nodpi...

thanks and hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can use weight attribute in your view so that it will take same percentage of space in different devices.... I have designed a layout below where two layout contains weight of 50 ... such that they take 50% space each in every layout.....

```
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        />

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        />

</LinearLayout>`
```